# Volley and GSON deserialize

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I'm having a strange issue and I can't figure out why. I'm trying to trasform json data from an http request into an object. Here's what I've done so far.

the class:

```
public class VersionInfo {
    @SerializedName("build")
    private String build;

    public VersionInfo(String v){
        this.build = v;
    }
}
```

the volley request:

```
private void getServerInfo() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "xxxxxx";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        VersionInfo vi = gson.fromJson(response,VersionInfo.class);
                        versionInfo.setText("vi is not working as an object");

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                versionInfo.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

the request is a php script like this:

```
 <?php
    $obj = array(
        'build' => 'Version: 1.0.0 alpha build'
    );

    $json = json_encode($obj);
    echo $json;
 ?>
```

And this is what debug show me:

[image]

My question is: Why this deserialize is not going to fill the `vi` object with the text given?

Answer (score 0):

As per `response` string in your `screenshot` your `VersionInfo` should be

```
 public class VersionInfo {

@SerializedName("vr")
@Expose
private String vr;

public String getVr() {
return vr;
}

public void setVr(String vr) {
this.vr = vr;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the @Expose. Anyway it's not working still

Comment: Well, there is a class named VersionInfo in some packages and I was importing this one and not mine....

Comment: Yes, As I said I was using the wrong calss, was just that